# Webpack config not applied in kotlin multiplatform react project

Tags: kotlin, gradle, webpack

I created a new Kotlin Full-Stack Application with the IntelliJ 2022.3.3 Wizard.
Aside from setting gradle to Version 8.0.2 and adding slf4j dependencies I changed nothing so far and the Demo Server and Frontend start up as expected.

I then wanted to change the Frontend port, among some other things, but I wanted to keep it simple.
So I added a `webpack.config.d` folder and a `webpack.config.js`.
No matter what Gradle Task I run, the changes are not reflected in the `webpack.config.evaluated.js` and thus are also not applied.

webpack.config.js:

```js
module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    devServer: {
        port: 8088,
    },
};
```

The build.gradle.kts:

```kotlin
plugins {
    kotlin("multiplatform") version "1.8.10"

    application
}


group = "de.splitframe"
version = "1.0-SNAPSHOT"

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven("https://maven.pkg.jetbrains.space/public/p/kotlinx-html/maven")
}

kotlin {
    jvm("backend") {
        jvmToolchain(16)
        withJava()
        testRuns["test"].executionTask.configure {
            useJUnitPlatform()
        }
    }
    js("frontend", IR) {
        binaries.executable()
        browser {
            commonWebpackConfig {
                cssSupport {
                    enabled.set(true)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        val commonMain by getting
        val commonTest by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation(kotlin("test"))
            }
        }
        val backendMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-netty:2.0.2")
                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-html-builder-jvm:2.0.2")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-html-jvm:0.7.2")
                implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.6")
                implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:2.0.6")
                implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.4.5")
            }
        }
        val backendTest by getting
        val frontendMain by getting {
            dependencies {
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-react:18.2.0-pre.346")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-react-dom:18.2.0-pre.346")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-emotion:11.9.3-pre.346")
                implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin-wrappers:kotlin-react-router-dom:6.3.0-pre.346")
            }
        }
        val frontendTest by getting
    }
}

application {
    applicationDefaultJvmArgs = listOf("-Dio.ktor.development=true")
    mainClass.set("de.splitframe.application.ServerKt")
}

tasks.named<Copy>("backendProcessResources") {
    val frontendBrowserDistribution = tasks.named("frontendBrowserDistribution")
    from(frontendBrowserDistribution)
}

tasks.named<JavaExec>("run") {
    dependsOn(tasks.named<Jar>("backendJar"))
    classpath(tasks.named<Jar>("backendJar"))
}
```

The structure is now:

[image]

Edit: I noticed that my settings are exported to the build though:
[image]

SOLUTION:

Thanks to @Benjamin-Charais I found what exactly was wrong. Aside from the location of the `webpack.config.d` folder, which has to be on the same level as the `src` folder the documentation (https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/) I followed was also not fitting here. The correct way to apply my settings is:

```js
;(function(config) {
    config.mode = 'development'
    config.devServer = {
        port: 8088
    }
})(config);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `webpack.config.d` folder needs to be at the same level as the `src` folder and the `build.gradle.kts`

Kotlin will automatically pick this up when running webpack based tasks.

As an extra note, only when a JS environment has the `binaries.executable()` will the webpack tasks be generated.

[image: Expected folder structure for webpack config in Kotlin]

When creating a new full stack project with IntelliJ, this structure will work and update the webpack config output appropriately when running the `jsBrowserWebpack` build. As seen in the screenshot it uses the proper values, and combines them with the rest of the webpack configuration.

[image: project with combined webpack]

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. Sadly it does not work on my end. From what I gather in your screenshot this is not a Full Stack Multiplatform Project. Maybe the problem is in the structure of this kind of project.

Comment: Updated to use the project, and show that this does work

Comment: Hey, with your answer to go on I was tinkering and found out why it did not work on my end. I was following this documentation here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/development/ but my changes were overridden by the last `module.exports = config` at the end. I then changed my `config.js` to follow how the other settings are written and it worked. I will update my question with the solution. Thank you!

Comment: If you also happen to know the answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75903286/webpack-devserver-cannot-find-bundled-js-script I would be more than happy. Sorry for the inconvenience.