# Webpack DevServer cannot find bundled js script

Tags: kotlin, webpack, webpack-dev-server

Related to: [Webpack config not applied in kotlin multiplatform react project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75848065/webpack-config-not-applied-in-kotlin-multiplatform-react-project)

As stated in the other Question this is a freshly created Full Stack Application from the IntelliJ Wizard.

I want to start the server/backend and the frontend separately. I had no issues with the server, but the some problems with the frontend. It doesn't seem to find the bundled js file when I start the task `jsBrowserRun` or `jsBrowserDevelopmentRun`
I added a `index.html` and a `webpack.config.js` and of course I also tried it without the `publicPath` or `historyApiFallback` options.

I also looked at [Webpack config: devServer.historyApiFallback and output.publicPath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55246361/webpack-config-devserver-historyapifallback-and-output-publicpath), but it didn't help me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="icon" href="/static/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

    <title>Niblette</title>
    <script src="/Niblette-frontend.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

```js
;(function(config) {
    config.mode = 'development'
    config.devServer.port = 8088
    config.devServer.historyApiFallback = true
    config.devServer.devMiddleware = {
        publicPath: '/'
    }
})(config);
```

[image: Files]

[image: Browser]

[image: Output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After executing the `jsBrowserDistribution` task I noticed that the bundled js file was not named `Niblette-frontend.js` like it is called in the other build folders, but just `Niblette.js`. Changing this in the index.html did the trick.